# Reactjs: How to customise the input field

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

In my project, there is an input field to add email values.

[image]

Those tags are placed inside the div element and above the input field.

the lines:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    items: [],
    value: "",
    error: null,
    editvalue:""
  };

  handleKeyDown = evt => {
    if (["Enter", "Tab", ","].includes(evt.key)) {
      evt.preventDefault();

      var value = this.state.value.trim();

      if (value && this.isValid(value)) {
        this.setState({
          items: [...this.state.items, this.state.value],
          value: ""
        });
      }
    }
  };

  handleChange = evt => {
    this.setState({
      value: evt.target.value,
      error: null
    });
  };

  handleDelete = item => {
    this.setState({
      items: this.state.items.filter(i => i !== item)
    });
  };
  
  handleItemEdit = item =>{
    const result = this.state.items.filter(values=>values!==item)
    this.setState({
      value: item,
      error: null,
      items: result
    });
  }

  handlePaste = evt => {
    evt.preventDefault();

    var paste = evt.clipboardData.getData("text");
    var emails = paste.match(/[\w\d\.-]+@[\w\d\.-]+\.[\w\d\.-]+/g);

    if (emails) {
      var toBeAdded = emails.filter(email => !this.isInList(email));

      this.setState({
        items: [...this.state.items, ...toBeAdded]
      });
    }
  };

  isValid(email) {
    let error = null;

    if (this.isInList(email)) {
      error = `${email} has already been added.`;
    }

    if (!this.isEmail(email)) {
      error = `${email} is not a valid email address.`;
    }

    if (error) {
      this.setState({ error });

      return false;
    }

    return true;
  }

  isInList(email) {
    return this.state.items.includes(email);
  }

  isEmail(email) {
    return /[\w\d\.-]+@[\w\d\.-]+\.[\w\d\.-]+/.test(email);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        {this.state.items.map(item => (
          <div className="tag-item" key={item} onClick={() => this.handleItemEdit(item)}>
            {item}
            <button
              type="button"
              className="button"
              onClick={() => this.handleDelete(item)}
            >
              &times;
            </button>
          </div>
        ))}

        <input
          ref={this.state.items}
          className={"input " + (this.state.error && " has-error")}
          value={this.state.value}
          placeholder="Type or paste email addresses and press `Enter`..."
          onKeyDown={this.handleKeyDown}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          onPaste={this.handlePaste}
        />

        {this.state.error && <p className="error">{this.state.error}</p>}
      </>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

My requirement is to place tags inside the input field, like this

[image]

I am a beginner in reactjs and I don't know how to do it, please give me valuable solutions to solve this problem

Comment: When you read the react concepts https://reactjs.org you will be able to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

```
//CSS 

* TAGS INPUT CSS  */
.tags-input {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  min-height: 48px;
  padding: 0 8px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(214, 216, 218);
  border-radius: 6px;
}

.tags-input:focus-within,
.tags-input:focus {
  border: 1px solid #2396F3;
}

.tags-input input {
  flex: 1;
  border: none;
  height: 46px;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 4px 0 0 0;
  color: #26323F;
}

.tags-input input:hover,
.tags-input input:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

.tags {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 8px 0 0 0;
}

.tag {
  height: 32px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0 8px;
  font-size: 14px;
  list-style: none;
  border-radius: 6px;
  margin: 0 8px 8px 0;
  background: #2396F3;
}

.taginput-dropdown-scroll {
  max-height: 121px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.focus-input {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.tags-input .form-floating {
  flex: 1;
}

.focus-input .form-floating {
  position: unset;
}

.tags-input .form-floating input {
  box-shadow: none !important;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}

.tags-input.focus-input .form-floating input {
  padding-top: 0;
}

.tags-input .form-floating>label {
  padding-left: 0;
}

.tags-input.focus-input .form-floating>label {
  padding-left: 8px;
}

.focus-input .form-floating>.form-control:focus~label,
.focus-input .form-floating>.form-control~label,
.focus-input .form-floating>.form-control:not(:placeholder-shown)~label,
.focus-input .form-floating>.form-select~label {
  opacity: .65;
  transform: scale(.85) translateY(-.5rem) translateX(.15rem)
}

//
const TagsInput = () => {
    const [tags, setTags] = useState<string[]>([]);
    const addTags = (event: React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLInputElement>): void => {
        const value = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value;
        if (value !== "" && tags.indexOf(value) < 0 && tags.length < maxTag) {
            setTags([...tags, value]);
            selectedTags([...tags, value]);
            (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value = "";
        }
    };
    const removeTags = (index: number) => {
        tags.splice(index, 1);
        setTags([...tags]);
        selectedTags([...tags]);
    };
    return (
        <div className="tags-input">
            <ul className="tags">
                {tags.map((tag: string, index: number) => (
                    <li key={index} className="tag">
                        <span className='tag-title'>{tag}</span>
                        <i className='ion-close-circled ms-2 cursor-pointer'
                            onClick={() => removeTags(index)}
                        >
                        </i>
                    </li>
                ))}
            </ul>
            <input
                type="text"
                onKeyUp={event => event.key === "Enter" ? addTags(event) : null}
                placeholder={"Enter tags"}
                maxLength={10}
            />
        </div>
    );
};
```